# allow custom header in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I need to allow a custom header called "secretToken". And every call to my webapi, the user should pass this header.

I searched for a way to do that, but I could not found an easy way. How can I allow this custom header?

Comment: allow means you want to check custom header of you are asking about passing from client

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal passing from client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned 'allow' means passing from client? Which client?

If JavaScript, you can do something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/values',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: { 'X-My-Secret-Token': 'Token' },
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

If .NET client, you can do something like this.

```
string url = "http://www.myurl/api/values";
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-My-Secret-Token", "Token");

var message = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

In Web API, you can read the header in `HttpRequestMessage` object from any component in the pipeline. For example, you can read the header from a handler like this.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                       HttpRequestMessage request,
                                             CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var headers = request.Headers;
        if (headers.Contains("X-My-Secret-Token"))
        {
             string token = headers.GetValues("X-My-Secret-Token").First();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's one more thing in .config file:

```
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,auth-key" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```